# php, order array by values (days of the week)

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a simple way to order this array (the days will always be displayed in right order)

```
  0 => "Thursday,Sunday"
  1 => "Tuesday"
  2 => "Monday"
  3 => "Tuesday,Thursday,Saturday"
  4 => "Tuesday"
  5 => "Monday,Wednesday"
  6 => "Saturday,Sunday"
  8 => "Wednesday"
  9 => "Saturday"
  10 => "Tuesday"
  11 => "Monday,Sunday"
```

in this ordery (by days of the week)

```
  2 => "Monday"
  5 => "Monday,Wednesday"
  11 => "Monday,Sunday"
  1 => "Tuesday"
  4 => "Tuesday"
  10 => "Tuesday"
  3 => "Tuesday,Thursday,Saturday"
  7 => "Tuesday,Friday"
  8 => "Wednesday"
  0 => "Thursday,Sunday"
  9 => "Saturday"
  6 => "Saturday,Sunday"
```

In the end I'll need to define the starting day but hopefully it should be easy to generalize the solution.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Next question is how do I rearrange the

```
    $day_map = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
```

to start from today `date('l')`. So if today's Fridey I would get

```
    $rearranged_day_map = ['Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday'];
```

And the answer to the updated question (the answer to the original question is below):

```
    //days
    $day_map = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    //order days to start from tomorrow
    $today = date('N'); // get today's day of the week
    $day_map_rearranged = array_merge(array_slice($day_map, $today),array_slice($day_map, 0, $today));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: Thanks. Should the function iterate through days of the week and if value in my array contains that string (let's say Monday) then move it to the new array? Then proceed with the iteration to Tuesday and so on?

Comment: @dbr The function doesn't iterate at all. It just compares the two items it's given, and returns a number that indicates which one should be first in the result. The `usort()` function takes care of iterating for you.

Comment: @Barmar I'll check the `usort()` tomorrow, 12hrs in front of monitor I can't think anymore.

Comment: Since when has Thursday come before Tuesday <grin>?!

Comment: @Robbie Fixed, did some playing with `usort()` got it to order the values alphabetically. ..

Comment: usort is useful. You should post your solution as an answer as other's may find it useful.

Comment: sadly it's not a solution, I need to order array by days of the week, not alphabetically

Comment: It seems from your question that you want to maintain index associations in your result, so you might want to use the [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have advised, you'll need to use `uasort` for this one. What I would do is `explode` the string first. Then create a default mapping for a day sequence (Mon - Fri) and use that for the sorting.

Here's the dirty idea:

```
// default order
$day_map = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
uasort($input_array, function($a, $b) use ($day_map) {
    $c = explode(',', $a); $d = explode(',', $b);
    for($i = 0, $len = count($c); $i < $len; $i++) {
        $d1 = @array_search($c[$i], $day_map);
        $d2 = @array_search($d[$i], $day_map);
        if($d1 == $d2) {
            continue; // skip, check the next column
        }
        return $d1 - $d2;
    }
});
```

[Sample Out](https://3v4l.org/OorR4)

Comment: Thanks! it worked. One question though regarding the 3v4l.org, what does it mean it takes 20MB to run the query? Will it occupy 20MB of my server for the 40ms? It seems crazy alot to me but I have no perspective on this so do tell me if I have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$roster = array(
0 => "Thursday,Sunday",
1 => "Tuesday",
2 => "Monday",
3 => "Tuesday,Thursday,Saturday",
4 => "Tuesday",
5 => "Monday,Wednesday",
6 => "Saturday,Sunday",
8 => "Wednesday",
9 => "Saturday",
10 => "Tuesday",
11 => "Monday,Sunday");

$day = array(
0 => "Monday",
1 => "Tuesday",
2 => "Wednesday",
3 => "Thursday",
4 => "Friday",
5 => "Saturday",
6 => "Sunday"); 

$result = array();

$x=0;
foreach($day as $idx => $arrValue){

    foreach($roster as $idxRoster => $arrRoster){
        $list = explode(',', $arrRoster);
        if($list[0] == $arrValue){
            $result[$x]['id'] = $idxRoster;
            $result[$x]['val'] = $arrRoster;

            $x++;
        }// end if
    }// end foreach

}// end foreach

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Wow, seems great except at the end I get `Sunday, Saturday` and `Sunday, Monday`. My code is a bit different so it could be it..